# JQuery Slide Up Hover Menu

Tags: jquery, menu, hoverintent

I need help getting the menus below the red box to slide up instead of slide down.
http://www.radiofriendly.freehosting.com/jquery/menu.html

Here's a working example. Just mouseover the menus below the blue banner.
https://partner.microsoft.com/germany/partner

Can anyone show me exactly what I need to modify in the js to get that to happen. Please be specific as possible. I'm new to Jquery. Thanks!

Comment: The menus are sliding up when you move the mouse out of the boxes. Or what do you mean with the question? Please be more specific.

Comment: @VisioN He wants the menus to slide up on mouseover, instead of slide down.

Comment: Yes, I want the menus to slide up.... here's an example. Just mouse over the menus below the blue banner: https://partner.microsoft.com/germany/partner

Comment: @HillBilly.Developer That's understandable, I did't get how this animation should work. Should it slideUp down, or should it slideUp to up (for *Botton Links*)?

Comment: @jimchang like this? http://jsfiddle.net/HillbillyDeveloper/dxwPC/

Comment: Yes, HillBilly! You're quick. Let me try to implement to see if I have any questions! Thanks!

Comment: I changed the plugin logic itself, which I'm not sure is the correct solution...

Comment: @HillBilly.Developer solution works but the menus show up "behind" other items. Fix is to specify a `z-index`. [Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dxwPC/1/)

Comment: @HillBilly.Developer can you tell me exactly what you changed in the code. I want to understand what you did. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the jQuery menu code:

```
if(opts.orientation == 'horizontal') {
        $this.find('.'+opts.dropDownClass).css('left', '0px').css('top', buttonHeight);
      }
```

to this...

```
if(opts.orientation == 'horizontal') {
        $this.find('.'+opts.dropDownClass).css('left', '0px').css('bottom', buttonHeight);
      }
```

I didn't look at what change @sachleen made, however.  There may be a better way, I'm pretty new to jQuery myself.